# How can to combine odds ratios and the confidence intervals

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to combine the ORs and confidence interval in one column so as to achieve the following results 1.10(0.52,2.29)

```
library(gtsummary)

trial %>% 
  select(response, grade) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `modify_table_styling()` function to merge two or more columns.  Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl <-
  trial %>% 
  select(response, grade) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = glm,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE
  ) %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = estimate,
    rows = !is.na(ci),
    cols_merge_pattern = "{estimate} ({ci})"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "**OR (95% CI)**") %>%
  modify_footnote(estimate ~ "OR = Odds Ratio, CI = Confidence Interval",
                  abbreviation = TRUE)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>